# Specific reason for suspension of specific user account at MSE

Tags: discussion, account-suspension

During my browsing through several pages on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/), I have come across several user accounts which have been temporarily suspended.

For example, one such account is *[Gone](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/242/gone)* (2,326 answers). This user has given many answers and some are really great. But the account is temporarily suspended. Whenever I click the hyperlink on [temporarily suspended](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/), it only shows the general set of rule violations for which the account is being suspended.

But it does not mention the particular reason for the suspension of that specific user. Is there any way we can know why some particular user account is temporarily suspended?

Comment: Why is it important to know?

Comment: If you look at the comment history on his Meta.MSE account, you can see what happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not active on MSE, so I don't know all the specifics. It was a quite dramatic happening in the early days of MSE.

#### Now, about your question:

We don't give the specific reason for suspension - that's how rumors get started. We still have to keep some info away from normal users - it's a privacy thing.

If we gave even *some* info beyond 'suspended', people would start speculating. We don't want that.